# Near the end of the Steins;Gate opening theme, why are only Okabe, Suzuha, and Luka looking to the right?

Tags: steins-gate

When I watched *Steins;Gate* for the first time, this part of the opening drew my attention:

[image: Moeka facing left (looking at her cell phone), Daru facing left, Faris facing centre-left, Luka facing right, Mayuri facing left, Kurisu facing left, Suzuha facing right, Okabe facing right]

The placement and the facing directions of the characters here seemed too deliberate to be arbitrary, so I felt like there was some sort of symbolism that I was missing. Do Okabe, Suzuha, and Luka have something in common that could explain why they're the only ones facing to the right?

Or am I overthinking this and the directions are just random?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I know this is over a year old, but I absolutely love the symbolism in this image, so I'm going to answer anyway. Maybe someone will notice.

All three of these characters have at used the  Unfortunately for anime viewers, Luka's travel only happened in the VN, making this pretty hard to pick up without playing the VN. Maybe they intended to adapt it at one point, but didn't end up doing so?

Specifics on the VN part for the curious:

> In Luka's route in the VN, Okabe doesn't reverse her D-Mail, and accepts that Mayuri has to die. After that happens, Luka uses the machine to spend time with Mayuri before she dies.

Anyway, I love how it has Kurisu with Okabe and Suzuha implying she's working with them, but stuck looking behind and can't look forward; always one step behind, but doing her best to help anyway.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the answer! But I'm a bit confused by your second paragraph, did some words accidentally get left out?